# How to manually complete the angular http observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, angular8

I am developing multiple parallel file upload feature with ability to delete/cancel ongoing http calls. Once all call gets completed/cancelled, I notify the consumer about it.

For this I am combining individual http observables using `forkJoin`. But in case user clicks on cancel button, I should not be waiting for the completion of actual http response.

<strike>**takeUntill won't handle it elegantly as it will act only after receiving the next value from underlying source http stream.**</strike>

```js
this.uploadFiles().subscribe(data => {
  console.warn("Upload completed now!!!!!", data);
});

uploadFiles() {
  return forkJoin(
    this.files.map(file => // returns array of observable
        this.uploadFile(file).pipe( catchError(() => of("Error re-emitted as success to prevent early exit"))))
  ).pipe(map(() => {
       // logic for some user friendly statistic
      return data;
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `takeUntil` with a Subject as notifier to complete Observables. You can pass a file id to the Subject and use `filter` in `takeUntil` to only cancel the file upload of a file with a given id.

Use `defaultIfEmpty` to provide a value that indicates a cancelled request. This also prevents the outer `forkJoin` from completing immediately when an inner empty request completes.

```js
private cancelUpload$ = new Subject<number>();

uploadFiles() {
  let errorCount = 0, cancelledCount = 0, successCount = 0;
  return forkJoin(this.dummyFiles.map(file =>
    this.uploadFile(file).pipe(
      // react to CANCEL event
      map(response => response == 'CANCEL' ? ++cancelledCount : ++successCount),
      catchError(() => of(++errorCount))
    )
  )).pipe(map(() => ({ errorCount, successCount, cancelledCount })));
}

uploadFile(file: any) {
  http$.pipe(
    ...
    takeUntil(this.cancelUpload$.pipe(filter(id => id == file.id))), // cancel
    defaultIfEmpty('CANCEL'), // provide value when cancelled
  )
}

cancelUpload(file: any) {
  file.uploadStatus = "cancelled";
  this.cancelUpload$.next(file.id) // cancel action
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zteeql-e1zacp

Comment: Take until is for ignoring the source observable and will wait for source observable(http.post in this case) and thus we cant aggregate the cancel status immediately.

Comment: In my stackblitz, forkJoin always complete with success since I emit the individual observable error as success.

Comment: @Amitesh `takeUntil` completes the source observable immediately and does not wait for the http request to emit something. If `takeUntil` completes the source `defaultIfEmpty` immediately emits a default value indicating a cancel event. You get immeditally notified about cancel events and can act uppon them here `this.uploadFile(file).pipe(tap(response => response == 'CANCEL' ? /* react to CANCEL event  */ ))`. `forkJoin` will of course still only emit after all inner file uploads completed.

Comment: you are right about `takeUntil`. I was under misconception without verifying :P

Answer (score 1):

Assign the subscription to the variable and cancel it with button:

```
$http: Subscription;
this.$http = this.http.post(this.uploadUrl, formData, {
      reportProgress: false
      // observe: 'events',
});
```

And in the cancel function:

```
cancelUpload(file: any) {
  file.uploadStatus = "cancelled"; 
  this.$http.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `takeUntil` we can also use `merge` or `race` operator to handle this scenario. However it doesn't change the underlying logic.

**Step 1: Create a `Subject` for individual upload**

```js
file.cancelUpload$ = new Subject();
```

**Step 2: Merge this subject with actual http call**

*merge will complete the stream if any of the observable emits the error. i.e when we emit error from `cancelUpload$` subject, http request will get cancelled automatically (look into network tab).*

```js
return merge(file.cancelUpload$, $http.pipe(...
```

**Step 3: Actual Cancellation Code**

```js
cancelUpload(file: any) {
  file.uploadStatus = "cancelled";
  file.cancelUpload$.error(file.uploadStatus);// implicitly subject gets completed
}
```

**Step 4: Complete the `cancelUpload$` Subject in case of upload error/success**

It will ensure that `merge` operation will gets completed as both stream is now complete. And therefore `forkJoin` will receive the response.

Refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zteeql?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhttp-example.ts

```js
  uploadFiles() {
    let errorCount = 0,cancelledCount = 0, successCount = 0;
    return forkJoin(
      this.dummyFiles
        .map(file =>
          this.uploadFile(file).pipe(
            catchError(() => of("Error re-emitted as success")) // value doesn't matter
          )
        )
    ).pipe(
      map(() => { // map would receive array of files in the order it was subscribed
        this.dummyFiles.forEach(file => {
          switch (file.uploadStatus) {
            case "success": successCount++; break;
            case "cancelled": cancelledCount++; break;
            case "error": errorCount++; break;
          }
        });
        return { errorCount, successCount, cancelledCount };
      })
    );
  }

  uploadFile(file: any) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const binaryContent = new Blob([Array(1000).join("some random text")], {
      type: "text/plain"
    }); // dummy data to upload
    formData.append("file", binaryContent);
    const $http = this.http.post(this.uploadUrl, formData, {
      reportProgress: false
      // observe: 'events',
      // withCredentials: true
    });
    file.cancelUpload$ = new Subject();
    file.uploadStatus = "inProgress";
    return merge(
      file.cancelUpload$,
      $http.pipe(
        tap(data => {
          file.uploadStatus = "uploaded";
          file.cancelUpload$.complete();
        }),
        catchError(event => {
          file.uploadStatus = "error";
          file.cancelUpload$.complete();
          return throwError("error");
        })
      )
    );
  }
```